# Бот на vk bottle выдает ошибку: 'message_read' is not a valid GroupEventType

Tags: python, vkbottle

Бот отвечает на сообщения как надо и продолжает работать, но хотелось бы избавиться от ошибки. Код и логи ниже:

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from vkbottle.dispatch.rules import ABCRule

class AdminRule(ABCRule[Message]):
    def __init__(self, admins: list):
        self.admins = admins

    async def check(self, event: Message):
        return event.from_id in self.admins

token = токен
bot = Bot(token=token)
bot.labeler.custom_rules["is_admin"] = AdminRule

@bot.on.message(is_admin = [айпи администратора])
async def admin_exe(message: Message):
        await message.answer("Админ")

@bot.on.message()
async def main(message: Message):
        await message.answer("Не админ")



bot.run_forever()
```

```
ERROR:vkbottle:'message_read' is not a valid GroupEventType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\real_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\dispatch\base.py", line 20, in route
    if not await view.process_event(event):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\real_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\dispatch\views\bot\message.py", line 35, in process_event
    typed_event = GroupEventType(self.get_event_type(event))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\levle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\enum.py", line 744, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\levle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\enum.py", line 1158, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: 'message_read' is not a valid GroupEventType
ERROR:vkbottle:'message_read' is not a valid GroupEventType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\real_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\dispatch\base.py", line 20, in route
    if not await view.process_event(event):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\real_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\vkbottle\dispatch\views\bot\raw.py", line 40, in process_event
    return GroupEventType(self.get_event_type(event)) in self.handlers
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\levle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\enum.py", line 744, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\levle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\enum.py", line 1158, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: 'message_read' is not a valid GroupEventType
```